# Git mirror a repo to specific branch

Tags: git, merge, mirror, git-fork

our company try to fork a github project to our own git server,then we can add our own features on it. We just want to checkout a specific branch, and keep all branches and tags up to this branch, then copy(mirror ?) to our git server.

Answer (score 9):

Create the repo on your server.  Elsewhere (not in the server repo), clone just the branch with

> git clone --single-branch --branch *branch_name* *github_repo_url*

Tell git where *your* repo is:

> git remote add mine *your_repo_url*

Then, push the branch to your repo with:

> git push -u mine; git push --tags -u mine

"mine" is the shorthand name of your repo, it could be any string, replacing the default "origin".

This will gather the entire history leading up to *branch_name*, but no commits that are not ancestral to it.

Comment: Good looking answer. But does this also grab the tags specific to the branch?

Comment: Ah! My favorite git mistake: you also need to "git push -- tags" to get the tags into the new report.

Comment: @stolenmoment, thanks for this great answer. But how can I mirror all the repo status up to the branch that I want? Means, if I want to mirror the branch-0.7, at this commit point, there will be branch-0.1, branch-0.2...(including tags of course), how can I do this? The purpose is I want to copy all the repo information up to the specific commit or the branch I want.

Answer (score 3):

1. clone old branch to local

```
git clone --bare git_url --single-branch --branch  old_branch_name local_dir
```

2. change dir

```
cd local_dir
```

3. add new remote

```
git remote add  new_origin new_git_url
```

4. push to new remote

```
git push new_origin  old_branch_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Stay on your local original repository and add new repo as your remote

```
git remote add newRemote NewRepoUrl
```

Then stay on a specific branch you want to push. Then push the codes to your newrepo that is in your new remote

```
git push newRemote current_branch_name
```

Note: **newRemote** is the remote name where I put my new repo url