# git: mirror a repository from a specific branch (bitbucket)

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, branch, mirror

I would like to have a particular mirror configuration with my repositories, in particular I would like to set a repository as a mirror of a specific branch of another repository.

Let's say I have repositories `X` and `Y`, I would like `X` to be a mirror just for the specific branch `B` of `Y`.

```
X <-- Y(B)
```

I have both repositories hosted on Bitbucket. Is it possible to do that? Could you suggest me a method to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible (reverse) approach could be the one suggested by [stolenmoment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2891476/stolenmoment) in the following thread:

[Git mirror a repo to specific branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38027834/git-mirror-a-repo-to-specific-branch/38028035#38028035)